# How to combine some matrix into one?

Tags: java, matrix, multiplication

I'm triying to do a matrix multiplication with divide and conquer. So, I think, I already have the descompose part into subproblems (the recursive case and the base case).

Thus, I have four quadrants (left superior, left inferior, right superior, right inferior) and I'm thinking about how to combine those into a result matrix, and I don't have an idea.

I'm working with Java, so I have matrixA and matrixB, and I have some indexes like, matrixRowsA, matrixColumnsA, matrixRowsB, matrixColumnsB

By this way I'm avoiding to create new matrix and all that stuff that only makes more expensive the problem resolution.

So the basic question is, how to join 4 submatrix into a fill one?

So the method is call divideAndConquer:

```
private static int[][] divideAndConquer(int[][]matrixA, int beginRowsA, int endRowsA, int beginColumnsA,
                                        int endColumnsA, int[][]matrixB, int beginRowsB, int endRowsB,
                                        int beginColumnsB, int endColumnsB)
{
    // Base case
    if(lengthOfBothMatrix()==1)
    {
        return multiplyMatrix(matrixA,matrixB);
    }
    }
    else
    {
        int middleRowsA = obtainMiddleRowsB();
        int middleColumnsA = obtainMiddleColumnsA();
        int middleRowsB = obtainMiddleRowsB();
        int middleColumnsB = obtainMiddleColumnsB();

        int[][] leftSuperiorQuadrant = matrixAddition(divideAndConquer(matrixA, beginRowsA, middleRowsA, beginColumnsA, middleColumnsA, matrixB, beginRowsB,
                middleRowsB, beginColumnsB, middleColumnsB),
                divideAndConquer(matrixA, beginRowsA, middleRowsA, middleColumnsA+1, endColumnsA,
                        matrixB, middleRowsB+1, endRowsB, beginColumnsB, middleColumnsB));
        int[][] leftInferiorQuadrant = matrixAddition(divideAndConquer(matrixA, middleRowsA+1, endRowsA, beginColumnsA, middleColumnsA,
                matrixB, beginRowsB,middleRowsB, beginColumnsB, middleColumnsB),
                divideAndConquer(matrixA, middleRowsA+1, endRowsA, middleColumnsA+1, endColumnsA,
                        matrixB, middleRowsB+1, endRowsB, beginColumnsB, middleColumnsB));

        int[][] rightSuperiorQuadrant = matrixAddition(divideAndConquer(matrixA, beginRowsA, middleRowsA, beginColumnsA, middleColumnsA,
                matrixB, beginRowsB, middleRowsB, middleColumnsB+1, endColumnsB),
                divideAndConquer(matrixA, beginRowsA, middleRowsA, middleColumnsA+1, endColumnsA,
                        matrixB, middleRowsB+1, endRowsB, middleColumnsB+1, endColumnsB));
        int[][] rightInferiorQuadrant =matrixAddition(divideAndConquer(matrixA, middleRowsA+1, endRowsA, beginColumnsA, middleColumnsA,
                matrixB, beginRowsB, middleRowsB, middleColumnsB+1, endColumnsB),
                divideAndConquer(matrixA, middleRowsA+1, endRowsA, middleColumnsA+1, endColumnsA,
                        matrixB, middleRowsB+1, endRowsB, middleColumnsB+1, endColumnsB));
```

I'm testing with two matrix like:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
```

Comment: Can you post your matrix declaration ?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: Is this really suitable for divide and conquer? Matrix multiplication for instance where you will use column by column from right to left and use with row by row from top to bottom.

Comment: I think it is, because you can descompose the problem into subproblems and get to a base case like two matrix of 1x1 which are simply a trivial product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can concat vertically the left matrices (leftSuperiorQuadrant & leftInferiorQuadrant) and right matrices (rightSuperiorQuadrant & rightInferiorQuadrant) into a new columns matrices with [System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```
    int leftSuperiorQuadrant [][] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    int rightSuperiorQuadrant [][] = {{5, 6}, {7, 8}};
    int leftInferiorQuadrant [][] = {{9, 10}, {11, 12}};
    int rightInferiorQuadrant [][] = {{13, 14}, {15, 16}};

    int m_intermediate_left[][] = new int[leftSuperiorQuadrant.length+leftInferiorQuadrant.length][];
    int m_intermediate_right[][] = new int[rightSuperiorQuadrant.length+rightInferiorQuadrant.length][];

    // Concat leftSuperiorQuadrant and leftInferiorQuadrant in column
    System.arraycopy(leftSuperiorQuadrant, 0, m_intermediate_left, 0, leftSuperiorQuadrant.length);
    System.arraycopy(leftInferiorQuadrant, 0, m_intermediate_left, leftSuperiorQuadrant.length, leftInferiorQuadrant.length);

    // Concat rightSuperiorQuadrant and rightInferiorQuadrant in column
    System.arraycopy(rightSuperiorQuadrant, 0, m_intermediate_right, 0, rightSuperiorQuadrant.length);
    System.arraycopy(rightInferiorQuadrant, 0, m_intermediate_right, rightSuperiorQuadrant.length, rightInferiorQuadrant.length);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m_intermediate_left));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m_intermediate_right));
```

This returns:

> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [9, 10], [11, 12]]

```
1  | 2
3  | 4
9  | 10
11 | 12
```

> [[5, 6], [7, 8], [13, 14], [15, 16]]

```
5  | 6   
7  | 8  
13 | 14 
15 | 16
```

Then, you can concat these resulting matrices horizontally manually:

```
    int m_final[][] = new int[m_intermediate_left.length][m_intermediate_left[0].length+m_intermediate_right[0].length];

    // For each row of the final matrix
    for(int i = 0; i < m_final.length; i++) {
      // For each column of the final matrix     
      for (int j = 0; j < m_final[0].length; j++) {
        // If j corresponds to the left columns, add left matrix values 
        if (j < m_intermediate_left[0].length) {
            m_final[i][j] = m_intermediate_left[i][j];
        }
        // If j corresponds to the right columns, add the right matrix values
        else {
            m_final[i][j] = m_intermediate_right[i][j - m_intermediate_left[0].length];
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m_final));
```

This returns your desire matrix:

> [[1, 2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 7, 8], [9, 10, 13, 14], [11, 12, 15, 16]]

```
1  | 2   | 5  | 6 
3  | 4   | 7  | 8
9  | 10  | 13 | 14
11 | 12  | 15 | 16
```

**Note that it won't work if your quadrants have different sizes.**

Best

Answer (score 1):

I still wanted:

- to point out, that the *division* in **divide and conquer** should be along the (multiplication's) algorithm's "break" lines;
- to mention the nice [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int)) class.

Doing a *sensible* division, the laziest effort, is important.
For matrix multiplication, a split in half seems more appropriate:

Very sketchy:

```
A: (3x5)      B: (5x3)    A x B: (3x3)
a a b b b     c c c       ... ac ... bd ...
a a b b b     c c c      
a a b b b     d d d      
              d d d
              d d d
```

As you see, you can split the task in Aa x Bc and Ab x Bd, and then cleanly combine the results.

This is sufficiently complex, and is also easy to understand.

An other tip would be to use more mathematical *short* names for ease of reading. Though ordinarily one should use adequately long names, and the course may require the contrary.

```
int[][] multiply(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int rows = a.length;
    int cols = b[0].length;
    int terms = b.length:
    if (terms != a[0].length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Dimensions do not match: " + a[0].length + " != " + terms);
    }
    int[][] product = new int[rows][cols];
    if (terms < 2) { // Cannot divide
        if (terms == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                    product[i][j] = a[i][0] * b[0][j];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        int half = terms/2;

        int[][] aLeft = new int[rows][half];
        int[][] bTop = new int[half][cols];
        ... fill using Arrays.copyOfRange ...
        int[][] prodLT = multiply(aLeft, bTop);

        int[][] aRight = new int[rows][terms - half];
        int[][] bBottom = new int[terms - half][cols];
        ... fill using Arrays.copyOfRange ...
        int[][] prodRB = multiply(aRight, bBottom);

        ... add prodLT to prodRB into product
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Hi, first, thanks for your proposal, second, I don't understand how to use the Arrays.copyOfRange, I was checking that method in the API, but, I can't find one which copy matrix, only I have found for one dimensional array. And respect the add prodLt to prodRB, can be like using a for loop which add prodLT[i[[j] to prodRB[i][j] ?

Comment: Forget the comment before, I get it now, thank you again!